# Why do IAM role statements like for S3 (arn:aws:s3:::) not work for other AWS resources like SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I have been successfully putting IAM role statements in my serverless.yml for S3 access for some time and assumed everything would work similarly when I added SQS.  I took the very simple arn:aws:s3::: and replaced the s3 with SQS, as you can see below:

```
  iam:
role:
  statements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:ListBucket'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - mahtestbucket
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:GetObject'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - mahtestbucket
            - '/*'

    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:ListBucket'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - mahfailbucket
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:PutObject'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - mahfailbucket
            - '/*'
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 'sqs:SendMessage'
        - 'sqs:GetQueueUrl'
        - 'sqs:GetQueueAttributes'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:sqs:::'
            - mahqueue
```

This deploys with no errors.  I can see the policy statement but it just doesn't work.  The lambda function fails when it attempts to access the SQS resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to post this with my own answer since it took me a few hours of wasted time to verify the policy was being created and determine what is going on.  I believe since S3 does not usually include a region definition, and buckets are global, the simpler specification works.  SQS and probably most other resources, however, need these things.  Once I determined this might be the issue, it took a little research to get the correct syntax working:

```
        - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 'sqs:SendMessage'
        - 'sqs:GetQueueUrl'
        - 'sqs:GetQueueAttributes'
        - 'sqs:ListQueues'
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - !Sub 'arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:'
            - mahqueue
```

Comment: That is correct. A bucket name is a **unique identifier** for the bucket, so there is no need to provide a Region or Account. ARNs for other services include an ARN and Account because resources with the same name can be created in other regions or Accounts. For example, I could create an Amazon SQS queue in my account with the name `mahqueue`, so a more specific reference is required.

Comment: And there is a middle ground for e.g. IAM resources since they are account global but not global global so they contain an account identifier but not a region.